# Transforming an equation into a squared form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, radicals

$$\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{4}+R^2+2Rs\cos\frac{t}{2}+s^2\cos^2\frac{t}{2}}$$

Is there a way that I can transform this equation into a squared form? so that when I put a root on, the root can be removed?

Comment: You cannot remove the root even if $\cos t/2=0$.

Comment: Where did the $R$, $s$ and $t$ crop up in the problem you are working on?

Comment: What should this radical be equal to?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel This is from the parameterised equation of the Mobius strip. The equation represents the surface element of the strip and I want to put that equation in the double integration in the process of using surface integral, so it would be much convenient if the root in the equation is removed.

Comment: That is a good enough context.

Comment: @N74 I don't know. I can't find any answer from the Internet. I need to solve is by my own but I feel like it is impossible. I need other's help.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Can you help me? Is there any particular transforming theory I can use?

Comment: Sorry, but no easy transformation is possible. Your radical is equal to $$\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{4}+\Big(R+s\cos\frac{t}{2}\Big)^2}$$ so is a sum of two squares